# PHP - Are class constants any different from global constants in terms of memory?

Tags: php, class, memory-management, constants

This is a question about memory usage in PHP.

- Is a class constant any different from a constant declared globally, in terms of memory use?
- Does statically referring to a constant declared inside a class require more memory?
- Does the class size (number & size of properties and methods) matter at all when statically referring to a constant inside it?

For clarity, class constant:

```
class Example {    
    const foo = 'bar';
}
```

global constant:

```
define('foo', 'bar');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never thought of this, but is a good question.

Searching a little bit, I found that you can use [memory_get_usage()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.memory-get-usage.php) to see the memory you are using before `memory_get_usage` executes.

So, try using it and you will see.

Do this:

```
echo memory_get_usage()."\n";
class Example {    
    const foo = 'bar';
}
echo memory_get_usage()."\n";
define('foo', 'bar');
echo memory_get_usage();
```

So there you will se how memory changes and that changes are the memory using.

I got this:

First echo: 349840
Second echo: 349840
Third echo: 349872

So, the difference is that the constant is pre-allocated, because if I comment class till the end, I get this memory `348664`.

So, empty script: 348664, with class only: 349840, with global constant only: 348976.

Empty script: 0
Class: 1176
Global Constant: 312

So, there is a big difference.

Comment: People have attempted [similar tests](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.constants.php#113559), but the results seem inconclusive. It could be due to paging.

Comment: Yes, it is pre-allocating, so, you have to do it without the classes to get a "zero" reference, and then see the difference, as I stated.

Comment: Interesting. So we can assume that once the class is declared, referring to the constant (eg. by ```Example::foo```) will not have any effect on memory use?

Comment: Yes, I have done that test, and the same ammount of memory was echoed

Comment: This doesn't tell you how much memory the constant takes, but how much the *class + constant* takes. Also, since strings are interned, you get skewed results if you use the same string for both tests.

Comment: also, the class should be in another file. My thought was that opcache would be smart enough to reduce it to a string reference instead of triggering the autoloader and loading the class into memory.
Defining the class in the same file defeats the purpose of the test IMO.